# Fastest way to get subset of array of items into a string?

Tags: c#, .net, performance

My method receives an array of positions that are used to concatenate some of the items in another array. Currently, I am looping through the positions and adding them to a `StringBuilder`, but is there a faster way? Does C# have some method that uses native code (similar to Java's `System.arraycopy`) to do a much faster "loop"?

Basic idea:

```cs
int[] positions = new int[] { 2, 5, 7 };
string[] values = new string[] { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight" };

StringBuilder concat = new StringBuilder();

for ( int i = 0; i < positions.length; i++ )
{
    concat.Append(values[positions[i]]);
    concat.Append(",");
}
```

Is there anything faster?

Comment: I can't really follow. How would you implement that in java using arraycopy?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
int[] positions = new int[] { 2, 5, 7 };
string[] values = new string[] { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight" };

var res = string.Join(",", positions.Select(f => values[f]));
```

Comment: Is this actually faster? lambdas tend to be slower

Comment: I'm not sure, hence I said try that. Lambdas add overhead, but the string.Join() method is a low level function so the result MAY be faster.

Comment: OK, I did some timings. Your method is the fastest at 80ms per 1M iterations, @nalnpir's modified solution is around 20ms slower and mine comes in dead last at 120ms slower.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know the for loop is one of the fastest loops in c#, in this case your code cannot be made parallel. So short answer is no, it cant be made faster.

Long answer, while there will be no performance improvement, there is no need to use a string builder here, you can simply append without the string builder. just delcare concat as a string and you can do something like this inside the for loop

```
concat += $"{values[positions[i]]},"
```

One thing to mention, while you might have taken this into account position 0 will return value "three" remember in c# arrays starts from 0

EDIT: From what the user Steve point out i did a lil try and error, and i found the fastest way is to do it like this

```
        string concat3 = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < positions.Length; i++)
        {
            concat3 += values[positions[i]] + ", ";
        }
        Console.WriteLine(stop.ElapsedTicks);
```

but we are talking about 5 ticks (with around 20 tries from each) of difference between the 3 of them so i wouldnt not even consider this to be a downgrade in performance

Comment: I was going to point out that this leave an extra comma `,` in the end, but that is exactly what OP's code does.

Comment: Yes thats why i left it there, i just made it easier to read but in essence its the same he wrote.

Comment: Concatenation is slower than using a StringBuilder, and using string interpolation slows it down some more.

Comment: I edited the question after trying it on my own @SteveTodd

Comment: @nalnpir Are you saying string concatenation was faster than string builder?

Comment: Honestly i think they re about the same time and the diference i got its simply due to how windows process things. What i can tell you though is from the results i got the fastest seems to be the string concatenation but by a hair. You could give it a try if you wish i recommend you to use the StopWatch class